# FluentNHibernate for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

am new to StackOverflow..

I am developing a website which requires extensive ORM...using asp.net MVC.

I have been trying to research and am still not clear.

Do u think using `FluentNHibernate` would be a good choice as a tool...or is there a better option?

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FluentNHibernate is really nice.    But it's semi redundant now as NHibernate has its own fluent mapping library.   So just use NHibernate out of the box.

It doesn't seem to be getting maintained as it once was.

Comment: Agreed. To complete this answer, I'll refer to the mapping-by-code guide I've written: http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html. It compares FNH to mapping-by-code many times, so you can know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tried the built in mapping for nHibernate and I didn't have much luck with them, and ended up going back to fluent nHibernate for now. The mapping is well documented in the link provided by Keith (it's what I used), but while the replacement for FluentNHibernate's mapping is there I have yet to find out how to achieve what FluentNHibernate could do for the configuration. How to you add the nHibernate mappings by code to the mappings of nHibernate?

Comment: See Fabio Maulo's examples how to add mapping-by-code mappings: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/nhibernate-32-mapping-by-code_13.html

Comment: Or maybe this one is better: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/07/nhibernate-playing-with-mapping-by-code.html

Comment: K, I'll take a look at that and try it out, hopefully it'll help me get rid of one more dependency.